# python email изменить письмо

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, rfc

Использую библиотеку email. Необходимо удалять некоторые вложения из письма и добавлять информацию о том что удалил. 
На вход поступает подобного вида письмо:

```
From test-sender@example.com
From: test-sender@example.com
To: test-recipient@example.com
Subject: test simple message

It's a test.

-- Best regards.
```

Следующий код:

```
text = ''
for attachment in self.attachments_pool:
    text+='Removed ' + attachment.getFilename() +' with hash: ' + attachment.getHash() + '\n'
text = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
self.msg.attach(text)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 209, in attach
    self._payload.append(payload)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "msg_parser.py", line 386, in <module>
    raise e
  File "msg_parser.py", line 376, in <module>
    main()
  File "msg_parser.py", line 369, in main
    msg_handler.handle()
  File "msg_parser.py", line 329, in handle
    self.msg.attach(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 211, in attach
    raise TypeError("Attach is not valid on a message with a"
TypeError: Attach is not valid on a message with a non-multipart payload
```

Я понимаю что письмо которое пытаюсь преобразовать не совсем валидное, но нужно из него сгенерировать multipart по всей видимости чтобы добавить туда что то.
Как это сделать? Заранее спасибо

Comment: А ваш self это какого класса объект? Мне кажется вы неверный метод используете для добавления текста

Comment: связанный вопрос [python email удалить вложение из письма](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/757855/23044)

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Attach is not valid on a message with a non-multipart payload

У вас сообщение без приложений. Один текст содержит. Чтобы заменить текст, можно `set_content()` метод использовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import email.policy

msg = email.message_from_string("""From test-sender@example.com
From: test-sender@example.com
To: test-recipient@example.com
Subject: test simple message

It's a test.

-- Best regards.""", policy=email.policy.default)

msg.set_content("Заменили текст.")

print(msg)
```

#### [Результат](https://ideone.com/qUwiB8)

```
From: test-sender@example.com
To: test-recipient@example.com
Subject: test simple message
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
MIME-Version: 1.0

0JfQsNC80LXQvdC40LvQuCDRgtC10LrRgdGCLgo=
```