# python email удалить вложение из письма

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, python-2.x, rfc

Я проверяю вложения в письме через антивирусную систему, если вложение вредоносное или подозрительное его необходимо удалить из письма и добавить текст о том что это вложение было удалено.

Как можно эффективно удалять вложения Content-Disposition: inline или Content-Disposition: attachment ? Обязательно ли собирать новое письмо (новый объект email.Message) и в него уже добавлять вложения ? Можно наверное как то изменить уже существующий объект email.Message ? А если нельзя как можно сконструировать новое письмо которое может быть любой сложности(надо скопировать все заголовки, все части письма например с помощью msg.walk) ?

Answer (score 0):

Можно думать о  [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) как о наборе заголовков и содержимом, которое может быть списком других сообщений (древовидная структура).

Отдельные EmailMessage объекты являются изменяемыми, поэтому можно по месту попробовать заменить. К примеру, чтобы [все картинки заменить на текст](https://ideone.com/z5du6i):

```
for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'image':
        part.clear_content()
        part.set_content("""\
Salut!

The image is removed.

--Pepé
""")
```

Вот пример как [заменить картинку на картинку (с текстом)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/758254/23044) -- может быть полезно, если по cid вставляется прямо в письмо картинка (чтобы текст видимым был в клиенте).

Чтобы сохранить сообщение в файл:

```
with open('no-image.msg', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(bytes(msg))
```

Чтобы отправить сообщение, к примеру, через gmail:

```
import smtplib
import ssl

with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', timeout=10) as s:
    s.set_debuglevel(1)
    s.starttls(context=ssl.create_default_context())
    s.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    s.send_message(msg)
```

Comment: Я получаю  File "test.py", line 77, in handle
    msg_part.clear_content()
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'clear_content'

Comment: @MNikita код использует EmailMessage, а не Message (используйте email.policy.default)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такую функцию:

```
def remove_attach(mail, mime):
    payload = mail.get_payload()
    if isinstance(payload, list):
        for part in payload:
            if part.get_content_type().startswith(mime):
                payload.remove(part)
    return mail
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]